# Javascript KendoGrid - Disable Column Resize

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I would like to disable resizing for certain column, and I found this on the Internet

http://dojo.telerik.com/AXAvi

The demo in the link above works fine. However, when I try to copy exactly the same code to my project, it just doesn't works .. It seems like binding the start function is not triggered when I try to resize the column in the grid .. can someone shed me the light ? Here's my code:

```
        var grid = $("#resourceNationalitiesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.resizable.bind("start", function(e) {
            alert("Function triggered");
            if ($(e.currentTarget).data("th").data("field") == "ID") {
                e.preventDefault();
                setTimeout(function(){
                  grid.wrapper.removeClass("k-grid-column-resizing");
                  $(document.body).add(".k-grid th").css("cursor", "");
              });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Does the `data("field")` really exist on your side with the value `ID` (case sensitive)?  Do you have any error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the mentioned chunk of code inside the databound event for the grid.

Alternatively hope you have specified:

```
resizable: true
```

during the grid initialization

Comment: Hi there, 

1) Yes, resizable is set to true
2) I put the mentioned chunk of code inside the databound event for the grid, it doesn't works either :(

Comment: Can you post a dojo/jsfiddle with a demo piece?